# Trouble seeing the contradiction in diagonalization proof

Tags: complexity-theory

[image]

I've seen the proof on a pdf online, and I'm having trouble seeing the contradiction.
If $(\langle T\rangle,z)=w \in D$, so when we emulate $T(w)$ with $U$ (universal machine), it accepts within the time bound,  so $M_D(w)=1$ and also $T(w)=1$.
Aren't you supposed to define $D$ as above, but accept only $x=(\langle M\rangle,z)$ where $M$ rejects $x$ within the time bound?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction, and the proof does not hold water. You are right: 'accepts' should be changed to 'rejects', and $D$ should be defined as

$$D=\{\langle M, x\rangle \quad | \quad M \underline{\underline{\text{ rejects }}}\langle M, x \rangle \text{ within }n\log(n) \text{ steps} \} $$

with $n=|\langle M, x\rangle|$, the length of the input. This way, the proof goes according to plan:

Proof. Suppose a $an+b$-time machine $T$ solves $D$. Take a sufficiently long $x$. Does $T$ accept input $\langle T, x\rangle$?

Suppose yes. Then $T$ accepts its input $\langle T,x\rangle$ within $an+b$, so $T$ accepts within $n\log(n)$. That's a contradiction, because by definition of $D$, $\langle T,x\rangle \in D \implies T \text{ rejects } x$.

Suppose no. Then $T$ rejects its input $\langle T, x\rangle$ within $n\log(n)$ steps, so $\langle T, x\rangle$ should be an element of $D$, so $T$ should have accepted. Contradiction $\square$